# Editing HTML by replacing text

Tags: parsing, html-parsing, jsoup

I am trying to replace HTML text from one language to corresponding text in other language, without changing the markup and layout of the page. For parsing HTML I am using JSOUP Java library.

```
doc.title(MTClient.translate(doc.title()));
```

This would take up the title of the page and replace it with translated text string output received by MTClient.translate(Text To Be Translated). This is working fine and replacing the title.

But when I am doing the same on Elements of the HTML page, using the below code:

```
Elements Nodes = doc.children();
for(Element node : Nodes){
    node.text(MTClient.translate(node.text()));
}
```

It is removing the whole layout of the page and only storing the translated text simply in the page.

I read the javadocs of JSOUP, which says:

```
public Element text(String text)
```

**Set the text of this element. Any existing contents (text or elements) will be cleared.**

And all the sub elements are removed.

I also tried HTMLPARSER lib in java, but it also doesn't seem to support this type of replacement.

How do i replace the text??

Thanks for help, in advance.

Comment: Just a side note, high-quality machine translation is a very difficult problem.  You're unlikely to get good results unless you have a very restricted vocabulary (e.g., a set of forms).  You might consider using something like the Google Translate API, even though it isn't free.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom Google Translate won't help as my language translation pair has regional languages. Google doesn't support these languages.

Comment: My aim is to make available Wikipedia in regional languages of India..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to modify the text, you should get the [Element's textNodes()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#textNodes%28%29) and [set their text](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/TextNode.html#text%28java.lang.String%29).  TextNodes don't have child elements, so you won't be replacing them.

```
Elements nodes = doc.children();
for (Element node : nodes)
    for (TextNode textNode : node.textNodes())
        textNode.text(MTClient.translate(textNode.text()));
```